# TextArea font not changing. ActionScript 3, Starling

Tags: actionscript-3, text, fonts, starling-framework

I have the follow bit of code

```
private var Text:TextArea = new TextArea();

        Text.y = stage.stageHeight - 185;
        Text.height = 170;
        Text.width = 1320;
        Text.x = 15;
        Text.isEditable = false;
        Text.text = "";
        Text.textEditorFactory = function():ITextEditorViewPort
        {
            var editor:TextFieldTextEditorViewPort = new TextFieldTextEditorViewPort();
            editor.textFormat = new TextFormat( "Consolas", 12, 0x333333 );
            return editor;
        }

        this.addChild(Text);
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I tried looking it up but i think this should work.
If anyone knows why this isn't working please post it here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you use the Starling textfield or did you use the feathers one?

Comment: @Duckdoom5 its the Feathers TextArea

Comment: Did you use a feathers theme?

Comment: @Duckdoom5 yeah, the AonDesktopTheme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into your feather theme's class and search for: 'textAreaInitializer'.

now find:

```
textArea.textEditorProperties.textFormat = this.chatTextFormat;
```

and change:

```
this.chatTextFormat;
```

into

```
new TextFormat( "Consolas", 12, 0x333333 );
```